# Cutting my kid loose from my PS account?

Tags: playstation-plus

So my kid is 15 now, and heavy into Destiny and other such games.

We've had a PlayStation for years, and when you first started needing an account, I created one for me, and the kids played on my account. When we started playing Diablo together, we all needed our own accounts, so I created them sub-accounts under mine.

Now, he's playing Destiny (and other games) on his own (with his friends), and for all intents and purposes, he's me... using my name, etc. I don't have a real issue with that, but I'd like at some point for him to be able to use his own account (so his friends don't pop up messages while I'm watching PSVue on my account, etc)... is there any way to transfer all of his stuff over to his own sub-account? I know that he could start from scratch, but at that point, he'd lose all of his DLC and all of his progress, etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: leaving this as a comment because I don't know if it is actually feasible: could you make your master account his account (change the email, name, screen name, etc) and then make yourself a new account? It sounds like you may not need anything that is locked to the current account so if this is possible, it may solve your problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Zero Stack, besides the purchased items there is no possible way to transfer account data in Destiny. The reason for this, is to ban the concept of selling account/items.
As a Destiny player, I think starting from scratch is not desirable in this stage of the game, while this is the only option for you.

[bungie post](https://www.bungie.net/en/Forums/Post/132824365)

[Bungie q&a page](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/12211)

Comment: Yes it does. Just because it's not the answer the OP probably wanted to hear, it is still relevant and correct.

Comment: There are those items that bring up your light level high enough to start Rise Of Iron missions, so your son won't keep the items he had on your account but will be able to skip the older content if they wanted.

Comment: @Vemonus that is an incendiary comment. The asker wished to know if the data was transferable. He has stated it isn't. This answer requires zero clarification whatsoever.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Apologies, the way the post was worded, it seemed like a comment. However, the comment wasn't incendiary, it was the default generated via the review queue. I didn't write it.

Comment: @Vemonus oh ok, fair enough. It just sounded harsh, but I guess that is the review system for ya.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I agree the messages could be softened up. You could try posting about it on the meta, but I can't guarantee it will be well-received.

Comment: @Vemonus - I think a key learning here is when using the review queues & flags - make sure you're reviewing every post carefully. :-)

Comment: @Robotnik will do. However, I think it's worth mentioning that there *were* 3 other people who recommended deletion. I just happened to be the only one who opted to add a comment. I think the answer was just unfortunately worded in a way that made it appear to be commentary rather than a standalone answer.

Answer (score 36):

It looks like you want to upgrade his account to a master account.  You can find the [details on how to do that here](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/my-account/access-and-details/what-to-do-when-a-sub-account-holder-reaches-18/), but quoted here are the steps below:

**How to upgrade a sub account**

Sign in to the sub account using Playstation Network sign in details:

**PlayStation App**
Tap the PlayStation Store on the home screen and go to  [Online ID] > [Account Settings].

OR

**PlayStation Store**
Go to PlayStation Store. Sign in, go to your Online ID at the top of the page and click [Account Settings].

OR

**Account Management website**
Click here and sign in for the account management site.

1. Select [Upgrade Your Account] on the Dashboard.
2. Read and agree to the SEN Terms of Service.
3. You may need to sign out and sign back in to complete the process.
4. You now have a master account

*Notes on this change:*

- Sub accounts can be upgraded using a web browser or PlayStation App.
- Sub accounts cannot be upgraded through Account Management on PlayStation systems.
- Upgrade to master account is permanent. The account cannot be changed back to a sub account.
- The master account to which the sub account is linked cannot stop a sub account from upgrading.
- Parental controls will no longer be active once the sub account has been upgraded.
- Any pre-orders placed by the sub account but not paid for from the master account wallet before upgrade will be paid for from the new master account wallet.
- Any new purchases and subscriptions will be paid for from the new master account’s wallet.

Comment: Sounds like that's close... but the purchases, trophies, etc are on **my** account, not his sub-account. By the time we discovered that he was going to be forced to have his own account, he'd already made purchases (and gotten trophies, etc) on my (master) account. The only reason that he's (currently) got a sub account is because DIII forced him to.... other than that, he uses my account.

Comment: You can always try contacting customer support, but I think it's unlikely that you will be able to split off part of an account into a new one.

Comment: @Cr4nky4nk3r You cannot transfer trophies nor savegames from one account to the other..

Answer (score 10):

No, I don't think this is possible.

You may be able to talk to Sony customer support, but I doubt they will be able to do anything for you regarding trophies and purchases linked to your current account.

He's just going to have to bite the bullet and start from scratch (his sub-account turned into a master).

Answer (score 3):

There's not a clean way to divvy up purchases made by an account, especially not by game. My recommendation to you is creating a new account for yourself and giving your kid your old one, then having your kid set your Playstation as that account's primary Playstation. This allows you access to all DLC and digital games you may have purchased on your old account, even with a new account. If he moves out, as long as whatever Playstation you have is set as primary for the old account, you will continue to be able to access those games. He will have access to any DLC he buys in the future despite not playing on his "primary Playstation" as long as he is signed in and playing on his account.

I used this method when my roommate bought a PS4 of his own and wanted to do something similar. I simply set his PS4 as my primary, and he set mine as his, and even though he moved out and I haven't seen him in a year, I still have access to all my old games (and new ones that he buys automatically download to my PS4, which is a nice occasional bonus).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid losing your sons progress, if you don't mind losing your own, you could make a new account yourself and let your son use yours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just giving him your account? You're obviously a more casual gamer than he is and you can make your new account the master account and he won't lose his progress/achievements. All of your friends will understand and migrate across to your new account in a couple of days.

Comment: OP said he didn't want that